# What happens to the low cut off frequency when replaced with a larger bypass capacitor?

Tags: bjt, power-electronics, common-emitter, cutoff-frequency

[image]

When the emitter capacitance is increased to 100 microfarads. What would happen to the low frequency cut off of this amplifier?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score -2):

You would have more bass at the output.